# Cannot access my computer IP through my mobile phone on same network with port

Tags: php, android, cordova, sharing

I am making an Android Application using Cordova(PhoneGap) which doesn't support PHP. However I can access it remotely on a server and execute, thereby returning html to display. But how to access PHP file on my computer through my android phone, execute the file using localhost port and return the html back on my display. Both devices are on the same network. I don't want to host the files on a domain as told by my project guide.

Comment: What you have tried? show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your problem, you want to access the files hosted on your computer (`localhost`) by your phone? If you're on the same network you can do that simply by routing with your phone to your computers IP address. You can get your IP address by typing the following code in the command prompt (`cmd.exe`):

```
C:\Users\yourname> ipconfig /all
```

Now you can see your IPv4 address in your network. Navigate with your phones browser to that IP address using the same network. If you're using a localhost port, do not forget to type that port after the IP address.

Comment: I tried this.....I think i need to do port forwarding....i have configured it on port 81 because i have IIS on port 80

Comment: So `localhost:81` works on your computer but `[yourip]:81` doesn't work?

Comment: I am not able to access with my mobile with IP and port 81

Answer (score 0):

Use a server like WAMP and save the files in www directory in the C drive(on the Windows PC).
Now you can access the files on the phone after using the ip and ports.

Comment: I am using XAMPP for my php development configured on port 81...I want to run the php file and get output on my mobile using my IP:81 . I am not able to do so. Is there a network configuration I need to do or there is some sort of problem?